# Linq to Entities averages within a predefined grouping

Tags: c#, .net, data-structures

```
I have used linq to entities to basically create an anonymous type with properties

bookId and rating which I have grouped by bookId. all I need to do is take this and 

form an anonymous type which groups by bookId and gives the average rating for this bookid

so anonymous type results currently looklike:


bookid = 1, rating = 2
bookid = 1, rating = 4
bookid = 2, rating = 3
bookid = 3, rating = 5

and the results need to look like
```

bookid = 1, averagerating = 3
   bookid = 2, averagerating = 4
   bookid = 3, averagerating = 5

averagerating just based on the grouping.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Given an anonymous type named bookRatingList which contains an list of bookRatings (new {bookid = somevalue, rating = somevalue}) you can use the following code:

```
    var bookRatingAverageList = from book in bookRatingList
    orderby book.bookid
    group book by book.bookid
    into groupedList
    select new { BookId = groupedList.Key, 
                 AverageRating = groupedList.Average(b => b.rating)};
```

The result should be an array of anonymous typed objects with BookId and AverageRating properties and ordered by BookId.